# HttpClient doesn't return the completed html source code

Tags: java, http, response, httpclient

I need to login to a website, click a few links to a final screen to download some data, here is the steps:

- step1: login into the site on the first page;
- step2: click a 'view' link on the first page to get to second page;
- step3: on the second page, put in 'account number', click submit button to get the many lines of data displayed, I call this as third page)
  (I get the direct URL to the third page, by pasting this URL to the address bar on the browser, the third page is displayed correctly)

here is my problem: 
I am using Httpclient. It passed the login page, and it can get to the third page, but it only 
return the static part on the page, the part dynamically generated data based on input 'account number' is not returned.

Here is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getHostConfiguration().setHost(loginUrl);

PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(serverUrl);
 // Prepare login parameters
NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair("passUID",account),
    new NameValuePair("passUCD",password)
};

postMethod.setRequestBody(data);
// I can print out the html code of the login page here

//request the third page with URL: serverUrl4
postMethod = new PostMethod(serverUrl4);
   NameValuePair[] data2 = {
               new NameValuePair("passUID",account),
               new NameValuePair("passUCD",""),
               new NameValuePair("page", "view"),
               new NameValuePair("procacct", "0"),
               new NameValuePair("AcctNo", "xxxxxxxxx")
   };

postMethod.setRequestBody(data2);
client.executeMethod(postMethod);
byte[] responseBody = postMethod.getResponseBody();
```

If I paste the URL with above namevaluepairs in the URL to the browser, the account data is displayed correctly. But the responsebody doesn't return the dynamically generated account data, anything else is returned but the section of the 'account data'.

Does anybody know why? any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Does the page in question use JavaScript to generate this data? If so, HTTPClient isn't going to be enough to get what you want.

Comment: thanks Andrew! it is javascript generated data. Can you please advise anything to resolve this problem?

Comment: not without know a lot more about the target page. If it's just making an ajax call to a webservice you may be able to emulate that but if it's doing on the fly calculations then you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be a `redirect` request(HTTP/1.1 302) from the server after you POST, check the status code of server responses. Also you should supply `cookies` which used by the server to identify logged in users.

**Edit:**

Wish this code snippet helps:

```
if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY ||  statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
    Header locationHeader = postMethod.getResponseHeader("location");
    if (locationHeader != null) {
        String location = locationHeader.getValue();
        System.out.println("The page was redirected to:" + location);
        /* **strong text**
        here is code to handle redirect to 
        "location" got from response headers
        */
    } else {
            System.err.println("Location field value is null.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the server returns SC_OK after I post.